# Unable to achieve Wildcard Routing in ActiveMQ Artemis 2.29.0

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am sending messages on different topics for example `queue.news.europe` or `queue.news.usa` using MQTT Pub Sampler from jmeter. There is a JMS Listener listening on `queue.news.*`. I have not created any queues on `broker.xml`,everything is created dynamically.
I was able to perform the above scenario on version 2.28.0. But this is not working on version 2.29.0. Has anything changed?

In the console under the attribute section for the topics, I can see `Routed Message Count` increasing when messages are sent.
Using `amq` password in Jmeter and in JMS Listener.
Broker Configuration is default - which is created at broker creation.

Comment: I set up a quick test for this use-case on ActiveMQ Artemis 2.29.0 and everything worked fine. I deployed a default broker, created a consumer using the command `artemis consumer --destination topic://queue.news.* --message-count 1` and then sent an MQTT message to `queue/news/foo`, and the consumer received it. Can you work up a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post it to GitHub or something so I can reproduce the problem you're observing?

Comment: Can you try with `queue://queue.news.*` on both the versions and let me know? I tried consuming using CLI in both version, 2.28.0 is working but in 2.29.0 it is not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application was consuming messages from the JMS **queue** `queue.news.*` then I would not expect it to work since a JMS queue uses *anycast* routing and given that MQTT is exclusively pub/sub any messages sent to an MQTT topic should therefore be routed with *multicast* semantics.

Prior to 2.29.0 the routing type was not set properly on MQTT messages which allowed this use-case to work. This behavior was a bug and was fixed via [ARTEMIS-4196](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-4196).

If you change your JMS application to consume messages from a JMS **topic** named `queue.news.*` instead I believe everything should work as before.